# Migrate multiple Craft 2 CMS sites on cPanel

Tags: error, migration

I am completely new to `Craft CMS` but need to `migrate` multiple sites at a current hosting provider away to AWS.

Due to a hard deadline, I have been looking at a lift and shift approach for the time being - using a cPanel AMI in AWS and then moving the sites across.

> Does anyone have any experience of moving sites `from cPanel to cPanel` particularly Craft?

I’ve tried one site already but get a `500 internal server` error when trying to browse the site. I’ve amended the db.php file to connect to the database and that looks ok.

Could anyone give me some pointers on the best way to move the sites and anything I need to look out for along the way?

Any pointers or recommendations would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have access to the terminal,if yes you can use git for moving all your site at once.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the permissions on the sever? As 500 usually comes due to `server permissions` or due to wrong `.htaccess` or wrong `Rewrite` file. Have a look at .htaccess file. 
And make sure to check your server error logs, they might provide you some valuable input for the errors.

If you find some specific errors, please share them so the community could help you better.